# Can the gerund clause take a personal pronoun as its subject in “It’s no use (his?) crying over lost love”?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, personal-pronouns, gerund-phrases, extraposition

From a gram­mar book, I’ve have learned that a gerund clause can be
op­tion­ally pre­ceded by a per­sonal pro­noun to show the log­i­cal
sub­ject of the verb; that is, who­ever is do­ing the gerund’s ac­tion.
I’ve also learned that a pos­ses­sive per­sonal pro­noun is usu­ally more
ac­cept­able here than a pro­noun in an­other gram­mat­i­cal case like
those used for sub­jects or ob­jects of fi­nite clauses.

With gerund clauses, there’a a cer­tain struc­ture that runs like this:

1. It’s no use **do­ing some­thing**.

in which *do­ing some­thing* is the gerund clause
and *do­ing* the gerund head­ing that clause.

My question is: Can we also add a pos­ses­sive pro­noun be­fore *do­ing*
in that par­tic­u­lar struc­ture?  So for ex­am­ple like this:

2. It’s no use ***his* cry­ing over** lost love.

Does it sound com­pletely nor­mal to use the pro­noun *his* there to say
who’s do­ing that ac­tion?

If not, is there some other way of say­ing it that would be more com­mon
and nat­u­ral-sound­ing to na­tive speak­ers?

Comment: Yes, we can do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Why do you doubt what you read in the book?

Comment: I thought so too. But I searched in the American Contemporary Corpus with the word string 'no use his doing' as well as 'no use your doing',  and found no matching results, so I feel unassured and turned over here to ask this question. As native speakers of English, could you tell me if I can add a possessive pronoun in front of any gerunds to show who does the action, regardless of what constituents they function as in sentences? Many thanks.

Comment: Because the grammar book is not written by native speakers of English, and far from enough is explained on this grammar point. Only a few example sentences are provided in the book. I am learning English where it's not a second language but a foreign language, meaning my scanty exposure to English materials and lack of grammar written by English-speaking grammaticians.

Comment: "It's no use his crying over the lost love" would not be idiomatic AE.

Comment: 'It's no use his saying sorry now' is rather old-fashioned and fairly high-register, but is totally grammatical. Look up the POSS-ing structure. // '...it's no use my trying to stop him.' Dracula, Ch 7_Bram Stoker.

Answer (score 1):

> In the grammar book, I have learned that a gerund can be preceded by a
>   pronoun (usually more acceptable, a possessive pronoun) to show who it
>   is that does this action.

Any noun can be used as the subject of the participial clause, not just pronouns. You should think of the -ing part as a clause, forget about the term "gerund". This and any other clause has to have the subject. It may not be overtly shown in the sentence, but it has to be understood, otherwise the clause wouldn't be interpretable. When you say: There's no use crying. the subject of "crying" comes from the context (rather than from the sentence).

As for the case, the accusative is as common as genitive (or even preferred choice). It was different in the past though. Here's from Jespersen's Modern Grammar, :

> With pronouns , we find both cases (nom. and oblique) used here, the
>   latter however chiefly in vulgar speech, which here as elsewhere,
>   tends to use the oblique in many combinations where educated speech
>   has the nominative.

Jespersen was a Dane, but he was obviously a good English grammarian. Don't let that bother you too much.

Comment: Many thanks, so could I interpret it as such that we can grammatically add a pronoun/possessive pronoun/any genitive of a noun preceding a gerund to refer to the logical doer of this gerund action, though it's not always semantically necessary in any cases?

Comment: You are welcome Eglantine! You should stop thinking about this construction as peculiar to pronouns. Subject of the ing clause can be any noun. As in any other clause, which subject you use depends on what you want to say and nothing else. "She likes Michael telling us stories". "She likes him telling us stories". "She likes telling us stories."  . You pick the subject you have in mind. In the last sentence the subject is not overt, but it is clearly understood from the sentence. It is coreferential with the subject of the main clause: "She is telling us stories"

Comment: 'the subject of "crying" comes from the context (rather than from the sentence)' is not using 'subject' in the way grammatical analysis demends. 'Crying' is non-finite, _not taking a subject; contrast 'cries' in '**Billy** cries a lot' and 'cried' in '**She** cried when she heard the news'._ 'Subject' is a syntactical term.  You want 'referent', though even that has conflicting definitions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you wouldn't say

> - *It’s no use do­ing **some­**thing.*

You'd say

- *It’s no use do­ing **any**thing.*

instead. There's a negative in the sentence, which is kind of like having a snake in your tent; you want to keep an eye on what it does. What it does in this case is use a negative polarity item *any* under normal circumstances. Using *some* instead is grammatical, but raises a question about why *some* was used instead of the normal *any*.

Second, the idiomatic construction

- *It's no use* `NP` `V`*-ing* (*Bill/Bill's/his/him/you/your doing it again*)

means Bill, or he, or you, shouldn't do it again, in the opinion of the speaker. The `V`*-ing* part is a gerund complement clause, with a subject noun phrase and a verb phrase, just like any other clause. The big difference is that gerunds are untensed -- they don't take any other suffixes for tense; *doing* doesn't say when the doing happens. Untensed clauses can't take nominative pronouns (like *I*) for subject; gerund subjects can be either genitive (*my*) or objective (*me*), while infinitive subjects (infinitives are also tenseless) have to be objective.